# Facebook - Who can use my page tab app?

Tags: facebook

Quick one:
Is it only I as the app administrator who can add the app to a fan page OR can anyone who finds it use it on their fan page(s)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the page admins can add an app to a page

They can do this via the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs) or the ['Add page Tab' dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/)

Comment: Ok, i only wan't my app to be installed on one certain fan page (our customer), how do I make sure no one else uses it?

Comment: I'd really be grateful to find a solution for this. Googled it for hours..:(

Comment: Use the 'page' parameter in the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) to determine the page ID, don't display content if it's the 'wrong' page